# Java DatagramSocket, Dart ClientSocket

Tags: java, sockets, dart, client, datagram

I'm working on a project which contains 1 Java server, 1 Android client, 1 Dart web client and 1 Java client. I got the Java server and client finished and working. Now I want to get started with the Dart client.

What's the best way to go so I can let Dart communicate with the Java DatagramSocket?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a Chrome App, which can access [UDP and other networking APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_network) (datagrams).

Unfortunately, a URL-based web app cannot access UDP. As mentioned in another answer, the browser can do HTTP(S), Web Sockets, and [WebRTC data channels](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/datachannels/).

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense! Thanks Seth Ladd!